# Network side updates to exchange personal address book

Tags: javascript, exchange-server, ews-javascript-api

I'm using @gautamsi `ews-javascript-api` to get my personal address book contacts programatically in my React/Redux app.  I can fetch my contacts using `FindItems`, but when I push a function to the `OnChange` array for an item, it never gets called when I update that contact from the outlook web interface.

First question, is it even possible to have a function called in my app when a contact is changed from network side?

Second question,

`item.OnChange.push(function(data) { console.log(data) } );`

Is this how I register a function to be called when item is changed on the network side.

Finally, is there a place I can register a callback to be notified whenever a contact is added or removed to my personal address book on the network side?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a response from the author of this API and thought I'd answer it here for everyone else.

OnChange functions are only called for local changes to objects.  There isn't a way to get notified of network side changes to your objects.